# If $\lVert F(z)^{-1}\rVert < M$. Then $z \to F(z)^{-1}$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I have the following theorem

> Suppose $B$ a **Banach space**, $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ is open and $F:U \to B$ is holomorphic such that $\exists~M~\forall z\in U, \lVert F(z)^{-1}\rVert < M$. Then $z \to F(z)^{-1}$ is holomorphic in $U$.

I'm confused in two parts. First, since it says inverse, instead of Banach space, shouldn't it be a Banach algebra?

The second doubt is in the part, $\exists~M~\forall z\in U, \lVert F(z)^{-1}\rVert < M$. I have two interpretations,

- $\forall z \in U, F(z)$ is invertible and $\lVert F(z)^{-1} \rVert<M$.

This being the interpretation I was able to demonstrate the result. For it suffices to verify that the inversion in a Banach algebra is holomorphic when $\lVert F(z)^{-1} \rVert<M$.

And the second interpretation,

- $\forall z \in U,$ such that $F(z)$ is invertible $\exists~M$ so that $\lVert F(z)^{-1} \rVert<M$.

This interpretation is stronger than the other one, as here it is not asking for it to be invertible in all domain. I believe there is a similar result for complex variable functions, but I could neither prove nor think of an example. Could this result be true?

Comment: If what you've written has no typos, it'd seem the proposition is referring to the reciprocal of $F(z)$ and not to an explicit inverse of $F$.

Comment: @JohannesPauling It doesn't have a typo, so it must be a Banach algebra, right?

Comment: $\iota:x^{-1}\mapsto x$ is differentiable  on the open set of invertible elements $G$ in the Banach algebra $A$. $F:z\mapsto F(z)$ is holomorphic and by hypothesis $F(z)\in G$ for all $x\in U$.  I think you can then $z\mapsto (F(z))^{-1}$ is complex differentiable (and hence holomorphic) as it is the composition of $\iota\circ F$.

Comment: Yes @OliverDíaz , this was my first interpretation and I managed to do this demonstration, but as I said, what if instead of $F(z) \in G~\forall x \in U$, we have the second interpretation that I mentioned, that there is a set $V\subseteq U$ such that $F(z)$ is invertible for all $x\in V$. It is probably necessary some hypothesis about the set $V$, perhaps density in $U$, this because I remember that there is a similar result in complex analysis...

Comment: The set $GL(B)$ formed by all invertible elements in $B$ is open.  Therefore, the set $\{z\in\mathbb C:F(z)\in GL(B)\}$
is open in $\mathbb C$, and this is the domain of definition of $F(\cdot)^{-1}$. Furthermore, the assumption that
$\|F(z)^{-1}\|<M$ is not needed for the proof of the result.  Nevertheless, since $F(\cdot)^{-1}$ is continuous, it is
automatically bounded in some neighborhood of any point of the domain.